# VPN connection blocking git requests - Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, git

For work I use a VPN connection to access our private network/servers. When I connect to the VPN it seems as though http/https keeps working fine but all other requests i'm having issues with, the biggest issue being git(working over ssh).

Whenever I try to run git pull/push while connected I just get a timeout and the server cannot be accessed. This problem does not occur if i'm using git over https.

I've had a look around and tried running ip route add with a few different parameters but have had no luck so far.

What's the best way around this? I know when I use viscosity on osx I don't have the same issue.

Comment: `What's the best way around this?` Have you asked the team that manages your VPN what's up?

Comment: The credentials are just from AWS and the rest of the team uses viscosity in osx/windows which seems to manage the connection properly.